# scrapy: what is wrong with this simple pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I have two scrapy spiders, let's say `spider1` and `spider2`. `spider1` crawls some pages and collects urls in a file. Here is the code:

```
class FileWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('somefile.txt'), 'wb')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if spider.name == 'spider1':
            line = item['url'] + "\n"
            self.file.write(line)
            return item
```

The problem is that as soon as I run `spider2`, `somefile.txt` is getting wiped clean. Would anyone know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what you do later, as soon as you call:

```
open('somefile.txt', 'wb')
```

with the `'wb'` argument, the [file is erased completely](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).  If you want to append, you should instead use `'ab'`.

Comment: ah.. and `__init__` is called before `process_item` so regardless of which spider it is it would erase it, right? let me check.`

Comment: It *has* to be otherwise your file wouldn't be open!